# Centering flex item content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following flex item (`#globalSearchContLi`) inside a flex-container. The container is an unordered list.

My problem is that I'm creating a fun looking search bar with a half-sphere submit button. The button is pretty much attached to the search bar with inline-block and margin properties.

This bundle (the search bar and button) won't center in the div any way I try to.

I tried setting `#globalSearchCont` with a specific width and auto side margins, but the whole flexbox presentation won't display correctly on mobile.

Any suggestions/advice? Thanks in advance.

```css
#globalSearchContLi {
  flex-grow: 7;
  margin: 0px 15px;
  flex-basis: 100px;
}

#globalSearchContLi {
  flex-grow: 7;
  margin: 0px 15px;
  flex-basis: 100px;
}

#munchGlobalSearchbar {
  width: 240px;
  height: 50px;
  /* box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px#000,0 0 0 3px #FFF, 0 0 0 5px #333; */
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #edad0c;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
  border-top: 2px solid #333;
  border-left: 2px solid #333;
}

#munchGlobalSearchbar::placeholder {
  color: #000;
}


#globalSearchBtn {
  background-image: url(../imgs/addOn/panEmoji.png);
  width: 50px;
  height: 51px;
  margin: 0px 0px -17px -12px !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  background-color: #38b32b;
  transition: .2s all ease;
}


.backImageCon {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<li id="globalSearchContLi">
  <div id="globalSearchCont">
    <input placeholder="Search..." type="textbox" name="globalSearch" id="munchGlobalSearchbar">
    <div id="globalSearchBtn" class="backImageCon"></div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `justify-content: center` on the parent to horizontally center the button elements.

```css
#globalSearchContLi {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
}

#globalSearchCont {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50px;
}

#munchGlobalSearchbar {
  width: 240px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #edad0c;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
  border-top: 2px solid #333;
  border-left: 2px solid #333;
}

#munchGlobalSearchbar::placeholder {
  color: #000;
}

#globalSearchBtn {
  background-image: url(../imgs/addOn/panEmoji.png);
  width: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  background-color: #38b32b;
  transition: .2s all ease;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.backImageCon {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="globalSearchContLi">
    <div id="globalSearchCont">
      <input placeholder="Search..." type="textbox" name="globalSearch" id="munchGlobalSearchbar">
      <div id="globalSearchBtn" class="backImageCon"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it. Although, I have no idea why it is that when I test it on my mobile device, the search bar looks much bigger (in safari) than in my desktop (chrome) Is this common?